# Finding a dymanic element in Selenium: "element not visible" error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a process using Selenium. I almost always use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

to locate the needed elements. As I go through the process, I end up clicking an element that opens a dialog box as such:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCo5K.jpg

The element I am trying to click on looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLlcy.jpg

The problem is that the xpath and the id are both dynamic, so each time I create a new session, I am dealing with slightly different information.

I located the element by using the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "56$187009")]/div[contains(@class, "gwt")]')
```

But when I try and send_keys to the element, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I can see the element on the screen but it seems the driver can not find it. I tried to use:

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, '56')][@class='WN5Q WCAR WCU']/input[contains(@class, 'gwt-TextBox WO5Q WBAR')]")
```

Comment: You are my night in shining armor. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @JoeyB Glad to be able to help you.